# What theorem should I use to prove the limit of a sequence is 0.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-writing

I am trying to find a theorems or convergence tests that can help me formally prove that this sequence converges to 0:

$$\{(3+n^2)(1/2)^n\}_{n\epsilon\Bbb{N}}$$

I am very new to convergence and divergence proofs, so I'm not quite sure where to start. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Informally, polynomials grow (much) slower than exponentials. In this case $\frac{n^2}{2^n}\to 0$ is sufficient.

Comment: Hard to know what theorems or tests to reference w/o knowing first which ones you've seen or have access to

Comment: Apply the ratio test: if $|a_{n+1}|/|a_n|\to a<1$ then $a_n\to 0.$ In your case $|a_{n+1}|/|a_n|\to {1/2}.$ Actually the ratio test implies that the series $\sum a_n$ is absolutely convergent, hence $a_n\to 0.$